# Me gustaría replicar la formula contar.si.conjunto de Excel pero en R

Tags: r, rstudio

Soy algo novato en RStudio y quería replicar la típica fórmula de Excel "contar.si.conjunto" que va contando los casos que suceden en una matriz en base a unos criterios para devolver cuantas situaciones. Y el caso es que no sé cómo hacerlo en RStudio o si ya existe una función para ello (¿si no, tengo que crearla yo?

Lo que querría, a modo de ejemplo, es: 
Dada esta serie de datos

```
1      setosa     Small
2      setosa     Small
3  versicolor       Big
4  versicolor       Big
5  versicolor       Big
6  versicolor     Small
7  versicolor     Small
8   virginica       Big
9   virginica       Big
10  virginica       Big
```

que en otro data.frame que yo he creado del siguiente modo se me complete con la cuenta de cuantas versicolor son Big, cuantas small... etc. Así:

```
Species        Big      Small
setosa           0          2
versicolor       3          2
virginica        3          0
```

siendo el conteo los resultado.

Answer (score 2):

Lo que necesitas es trabajar con la función base [`table()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.1/topics/table) que te permite crear una tabla de clasificación. En tu caso que tienes un `data.frame` como el siguiente:

```
df <- read.table(text="Tipo    Tamaño
      setosa     Small
      setosa     Small
  versicolor       Big
  versicolor       Big
  versicolor       Big
  versicolor     Small
  versicolor     Small
   virginica       Big
   virginica       Big
   virginica       Big", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Nota: Lo anterior, solo es para hacer reproducible la solución.

Simplemente puedes hacer:

```
table(df)

            Tamaño
Tipo         Big Small
  setosa       0     2
  versicolor   3     2
  virginica    3     0
```

Si tuvieras más columnas y solo deseas considerar el `Tipo` y `Tamaño` puedes hacer: `table(df[, c("Tipo", "Tamaño")])`